# How to import image dynamically with Nuxt+jQuery script

Tags: jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js, jquery-select2

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select ref='select'>
            <slot></slot>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue"
export default {
    name: "VueSelect",
    props: ['options', 'value'],

    mounted: function () {
        var vm = this;
        $(this.$refs.select)
            .select2({
                data: this.options,
                tags: true,
                theme: "bootstrap",
                createTag: function (params) {
                    return {
                        id: params.term,
                        text: params.term,
                        newOption: true
                    }
                },
                templateResult: function (state) {
                    console.log(state)
                    if (!state.id) {
                        return state.text;
                    }
                    var baseUrl = "/dist/peoples";
                    var imgUrl = baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png'

                    var $state = $(
                        '<span><img src="'+imgUrl+'" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
                    );
                    return $state;
                }
            })
            .on('change', function (ev, args) {
                if (!(args && "ignore" in args)) {
                    vm.$emit('input', $(this).val());
                    vm.$emit("change_value",$(this).val())
                }
            });

        Vue.nextTick(() => {
            $(this.$refs.select)
                .val(this.value)
                .trigger('change', { ignore: true })
        });
    },
    methods: {
        getImageUrl: function(src) {
            return require("~/assets"+src);
        }
    },  
    watch: {
        value: function (value, oldValue) {
            // update value
            $(this.$refs.select)
                .val(this.value)
                .trigger('change', { ignore: true });
        },
        options: function (options) {
            // update options
            $(this.$refs.select).select2({ data: options })
        }
    },
    destroyed: function () {
        $(this.$refs.select).off().select2('destroy')
    }
}

</script>

<style>
.select2-container--default {
    min-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Here's my Vue + Select2 component.

The issue is that I can't import image dynamically within jQuery script.

```
 var baseUrl = "~/assets/images/peoples";
 var imgUrl = baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png'
```

I have tried as follows according to the Nuxt dynamic import guide

```
 var baseUrl = "~/assets/images/peoples";
 var imgUrl = require(baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value.toLowerCase() + '.png')
```

But it fails.

The console says "Cannot find module "~/assets/images/peoples/10.png" "

also I can't import using static folder ( I copied them to it) with "var baseUrl = "/static/images/people"

The console says "localhost:3000/static/images/people/10.png" cannot found".

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not trying to fully answer your question here but what I know is that if you're using 'static' folder to serve images, you should use it without using the word 'static' in your URL. For example:

```
var baseUrl = "/static/images/people"
```

should be

```
var baseUrl = "/images/people"
```

which will then serve from

```
localhost:3000/images/people/10.png
```

I could have commented but my reputation is too low to comment but good enough to submit an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in static, you only to have `/images/people` as mentioned by Raju. Also, I would recommend quite a simple solution: skip jQuery and use a Vue package for that one rather. You will have a far better API and less bugs overall.

Give a try to a well maintained and good matching package here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#select

jQuery is too messy, get's into Vue's reactivity way of things and is bringing a big load of JS for "nothing" since Vue can make as good with it's own API.